# JAXB Unmarshal of international characters results in question marks (?)

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

I have been stumped by this issue for several weeks now.  I have an XML document that I receive from an Autonomy IDOL search and can successfully unmarshal it into a set of Java objects.  However, if there are international characters, such as Chinese, Japanese, Russian/Cyrillic, they are converted into question marks (?).

The first line of the XML document sets the encoding as UTF-8: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

I am using the following code for the Unmarshal operation:

```
public static AutnResponse convertXmlToResponse(String xml) {
    AutnResponse resp = null;

    try {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(AutnResponse.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

        resp = (AutnResponse) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()),"UTF-8"));
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Caught exception trying to unmarshal XML file: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

    return resp;
}
```

Is there something I am overlooking?  Any help, tips or other resources would be very much appreciated.  I have searched countless Google listings but cannot resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
xml.getBytes()
```

...should be...

```
xml.getBytes("UTF-8")
```

...so that the transcoding operations are symmetrical.

But since already have character data, just use...

```
unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
```

Comment: Thanks for those tips.  I tried both ways and I'm still getting the question marks.

Comment: @ctg2366 - Where are you seeing the question marks?  I have seen cases where JAXB is handling the characters correctly but peoples editors are not capable and they see question marks when viewing the doc even when the actual doc is ok.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan thanks for the response.  Your comment got me thinking about that.  I am running this in Eclipse and was seeing the question marks in the console as well as on the JSP page where I am sending the data.  However, I changed the default charset in Eclipse to UTF-8 and outputting the data after Unmarshalling and now I am seeing the international characters correctly.  However, they are still displaying as question marks in the browser after being rendered by the JSP. I will look at the JSP code now.

Comment: @ctg2366 - I have added an answer based on my comment:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20958191/383861

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that JAXB is rendering the characters correctly.  The problem may be the tool you are using to view the resulting document.

---

**UPDATE**

> @BlaiseDoughan thanks for the response. Your comment got me thinking
>   about that. I am running this in Eclipse and was seeing the question
>   marks in the console as well as on the JSP page where I am sending the
>   data. However, I changed the default charset in Eclipse to UTF-8 and
>   outputting the data after Unmarshalling and now I am seeing the
>   international characters correctly. However, they are still displaying
>   as question marks in the browser after being rendered by the JSP. I
>   will look at the JSP code now.

Based on your investigation this appears to be the issue.

Comment: Problem finally solved.  My JSP page was missing the following tag:  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>  The page had the tag <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> in the HEAD but that is not enough.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

xml.getBytes("UTF-8")

but before doing that you need to save your java file "Save as UTF", if you are using Eclipse.

Then JAXB can happily generate the XML with Chinese, Japanese or any other language characters.

Another point I need to mention here, if any kind of font issues are coming your way, e.g. if Chinese fonts are displaying as ???? then you have to convert your Eclipse project to UTF8, then happily your code will support it. Also you must take care about the fonts already available on the system.